# get contents of source block

Tags: org-babel

I'm trying go get the src block contents with `(org-element-property :value (org-element-at-point))`, but when I apply this on a block like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(print "foo")
#+END_SRC
```

the result is `(print \"foo\")`. How can I get the exact contents from the block as a string ?

Comment: Is it possible you are getting the exact contents and  `(print \"foo\")` is how emacs displays it? (since `"(print "foo" )"` is two different strings with the word `foo` in between). Is it that you want to print the exact contents `(print "foo")` out to the buffer?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I should have taken another look at it before asking. It's actually not about printing. My problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, it returns `"(print \"foo\")\n"` from here with Org 9.1.9. Note that `\n` might be rendered when `print-escape-newlines` is nil.